# Configure request timeout on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Is it possible to configure the request timeout on heroku?

I have some report queries that that take longer than the default 30 seconds heroku provides. Ideally, I'd like to set it for specific requests (just the reports).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku seems to [encourage responses of 500ms or less](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout). Since they don't mention altering the request timeout on that page my guess would be that they don't support changing it (though you could ask Heroku Support).

What kind of work are you doing for your report?

1. Can you run calculation work in a background job and store the result? (e.g. in memcache, in another table in your database, etc) How up-to-date does the information need to be?
2. Can you speed up your query? What does your query plan look like? Is there room for improvement by changing how the data is queried or adding indexes?
3. Would an approach like HTTP streaming help?

I would suggest trying approaches 1 or 2 first and seeing if they help. If you give us more detail on what exactly you're doing we may be able to help more.

Comment: I know for some of our reports we are running a background process for later access, so that will likely need to be done for these as well. From what I've seen so far, it doesn't look like a possibility to adjust any of the server configs.