# Rails asset pipeline workflow when there are hundreds of asset files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

We recently converted a Rails 3.2 project to use the asset pipeline. Our app uses *many* asset files (~250 *.js.coffee files, another 200 or so *.jst.hamljs templates, and ~100 *.css.sass stylesheets). As you'd expect, these are packaged into a much smaller number of asset files in production.

In development and test environments, we deal with frequent timeouts and *slow* page-loads while recompiling and requesting individual assets. Is there a better workflow that still allows automatic recompilation?

We're running with default environment settings, except have set `debug` to `false` in development:

```
config.assets.debug = false
```

This saves us hundreds of requests when reloading the page in development, but initial compilation still causes timeouts. There must be a better way, right?

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- Limit what is required to be recompiled when requested via use of `require_asset`. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13180417/178651) and Sprockets [#90](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/90).
- Precompile assets:

  ```
  $ RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile
  ```
- Increase timeouts. This depends on how you have things setup and can be painful and problematic, e.g. Heroku is [not a big fan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11963222/178651) of [long requests](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout).
- Use a faster interpreter.
- Faster hardware/VM.

Comment: You're right about Heroku being a stickler for resources.  Perhaps something like Engine Yard would be a better fit for an of a such size?

Comment: As long as there is some communication between server and client, Heroku allows long running requests, and users shouldn't be waiting on assets to compile for too long, so I can't say that I disagree with them or that EY would be a better choice based on that. If you're trying to get in a plug for EY, that's cool though. :)

Comment: To clarify with respect to the Heroku/EY issue, the original question relates to development/test environments. The production environment functions correctly because the many asset files are precompiled and packaged into a reasonable number of includes.

Comment: Ok, then I would first try using `require_asset` as Josh Peek said in Sprockets #90 and as mentioned in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13180417/178651 to avoid compilation of things you don't need. The Heroku comment is there for others that might be drawn to this page as something to think about.

Answer (score 0):

Are you precompiling the assets in development?

`bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

That should keep the assets from recompiling each time.

Comment: **but initial compilation still causes timeouts**

Comment: @apneadiving I think the OP meant the request was timing out vs. precompilation, but dk.

Comment: As @apneadiving points out, precompilation isn't the problem. I _want_ assets to recompile after they've been updated (as they're designed to do--this is development/test after all). The problem is the "fresh" state... I need to wait 5 minutes and repeatedly reload after timeouts while all of the assets get initially compiled.

Comment: Ok, understand now. Had assumed that you were just trying to stop the timeout in development/test, and precompiling in development/test (after making each change) is an option if you've already limited what you are compiling at runtime via require_asset as I mentioned in my answer. After that, if compilation is the bottleneck, then you're going to have to make compilation itself faster somehow, most likely.